# Rails input form boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I got problem with make form where i can chose between true or false.
In model ticket i got:
`type:boolean`

When i'm making check_box in form i got this error msg:

`Invalid single-table inheritance type: 1 is not a subclass of Ticket`

My form code: 
`<%= form_for [@movie, @seance, @ticket] do |f| %>`
`<div>`

 `<%= f.label :type %>`
`<%= f.check_box :type %>`
 `<%end%>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` is a reserved word in ruby-on-rails, used for STI.

Change your column name to, say, `:ticket_type`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Single Table Inheritance 'type' column, changing the name for something else.

**self.inheritance_column = :fake_column**

https://devblast.com/b/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1

Comment: please try to improve your answer making it more clear. If you want you can copy & paste relevant information from the page you linked *devblast...* just put between quotes. Also it is not clear why he/she is getting the error.